# Request had insufficient authentication scopes for classroom announcements

Tags: python, api, google-classroom

I am using python api for fetching announcements from classroom.

My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from os import getcwd
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

class ClassRoom:
    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
    def announcements_list(self):
        self.SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly', 
                       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements.readonly']
        """Shows basic usage of the Classroom API.
        Prints the names of the first 10 courses the user has access to.
        """
        creds = None
        # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', self.SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

        service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Classroom API
        results = service.courses().list(pageSize=10).execute()
        courses = results.get('courses', [])
        announcements = []
        for course in course:
            announcements += service.courses().announcements().list(courseId=course["id"], 
                             pageSize=1).execute().get("annoucements")
        return announcements

cs = ClassRoom()
print(cs.announcements_list())
```

But the script is generating HttpError 403 error something like
"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: After changing your scopes, did you delete your token file in order to trigger new authorization flow?

Comment: yes but didn't help

Comment: Are you a teacher, student or admin? Do you have ther permissions to access the specified course and its announcements? did you test with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list) feature?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, delete token.pickle from your folder and execute again. it should work